# How to resolve different signature error

Tags: android, signature

I got Calculator source code from google's android.git.kernel.org and successfully build the project without problem. But when I launch it in eclipse, I got this

```
Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2011-08-14 03:37:04 - JvCalculator] You must perform a full uninstall of the application.     WARNING: This will remove the application data! 
[2011-08-14 03:37:04 - JvCalculator] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.android.calculator2' in a shell.
[2011-08-14 03:37:04 - JvCalculator] Launch canceled!
```

I don't think I have the application in my emulator. So it's not uninstall/install problem, I think. I suspect that the google's source code has different signature. If so how I can change it? Is there anybody that resolved this issue? Or do I have to build a new project with copy and paste?

Note that when I tried following while connecting emulator,

```
adb uninstall com.android.calculator2
```

I got a simple one-word error message "Failure".

Comment: These apps are not designed to be built and installed except via building and installing a full custom firmware.

Comment: I didn't know that's the default calculator. It makes sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"How can I install Calculator (or any app) from the git repository (or from source) to any device that already has it installed?"  You can't change the signature because that is a closely guarded secret at Google or (any other app developer). What you can do is change the application's package, with a different package the system will think its a different app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying what you suggested. Can I just rename of application package? Or is there any other thing I need to do?

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your explanation. I am learning so much. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. Uninstalling via adb did the trick:

```
    adb -d uninstall org.janeullah.android.healthrecords
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try making a new emulator.
2. Try cleaning the project.

Comment: you were not answering my question, not even close. But I am thankful for your answer anyway. Thus +1

Answer (score 0):

Had same error, but I was testing the app on a device that had the app already installed (some old version). After uninstalling it worked without renaming the packages or other changes.